# How to create a title page for a PDF document created using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdfpages

I have a report to be submitted automatically and I am using matplotlib to do that. But I am not able to figure out how to create a blank page in the begining with Title in the middle on the type of analysis which is performed

```
with PdfPages('review_count.pdf') as pdf:
    for cat in self.cat_vars.keys():
        if len(self.cat_vars[cat]) > 1:
            plt.figure()
            self.cat_vars[cat].plot(kind='bar')
            plt.title(cat)
            # saves the current figure into a pdf page
            pdf.savefig()
            plt.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just be able to create a figure before your `for` loop with the title on. You also need to turn the axis frame off (`plt.axis('off')`).

```
with PdfPages('review_count.pdf') as pdf:
    plt.figure() 
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.text(0.5,0.5,"my title",ha='center',va='center')
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close() 
    for cat in self.cat_vars.keys():
        if len(self.cat_vars[cat]) > 1:
            plt.figure()
            self.cat_vars[cat].plot(kind='bar')
            plt.title(cat)
            # saves the current figure into a pdf page
            pdf.savefig()
            plt.close()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!. In addition to this if u add  'plt.axis('off')'  it will also remove the axis

Comment: @BharathKumar thanks, I updated the answer with that. Also realised you need to set the vertical and horizontal alignment to get the title truly in the center